# Why is multiple uploading not getting inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading, codeigniter-3

Here I am trying to insert multiple images into the database but they are not inserted. The images are uploading to the folder correctly but don't know  why its not entering in to the database.
Here is my image upload function

```
public function multiple_upload_files($path)
{
    $images = array();
    if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'])){
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
          $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
          $config['upload_path']= './uploads/'.$path.'/';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
          $config['max_size']= '2000';
          $config['max_width'] = '4000';
          $config['max_height'] = '6500';
          $config['file_name']='upld-file'.time();
          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
          $this->upload->initialize($config);
         if ($this->upload->do_upload("file")) {

           $images[] = $this->upload->data();
        }
        else {  
         redirect('admin/view-product');

        }
    }
           return $images;
}
```

Here is my inserting code

```
$path='products';
     if($this->multiple_upload_files($path))
     {
      $img=implode(',',$images);
      $data = array('product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),'image'=>$img);
      $status = $this->Admin_model->db_insert($table='products',$data);
        if($status)
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Product added Successfully');
        }
        else
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Insertion failed');
        }
```

The problem is the images are uploaded to the uploaded folder but not to the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple image upload with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778683/multiple-image-upload-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning array of images from method but not receiving it. change you code as below

```
 $path='products';
 $images= $this->multiple_upload_files($path);
 if($images)
 {
  $img=implode(',',$images);
  $data = array('product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),'image'=>$img);
  $status = $this->Admin_model->db_insert($table='products',$data);
    if($status)
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Product added Successfully');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Insertion failed');
    }
```