# How to save images inside a form with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3, image-uploading, form-submit

So I have a form with some text field and three file field too. On submit I want to insert the new user into my database and I want to save the three individual files (images) with different names to my server. I read about CodeIgniter's file uploading class but I am not able to implement it into my code.

That's what I tried.

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('login');
    }
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/test_view');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function newUser(){
    $this->load->model('TestModel');

    $new_user = array (
        'FirstName' => $this->input->post('inputFirstName'),
        'LastName' => $this->input->post('inputLastName')
    );

    $insert_id = $this->TestModel->insertNewUser($new_user);

    $config['upload_path'] = base_url().'img/users/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $insert_id."_index";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('index'))
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    } else {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    $config['file_name'] = $insert_id."_picture1";
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture1'))
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    } else {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    $config['file_name'] = $insert_id."_picture2";
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture2'))
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    } else {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    //redirect('test');
}
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary margin-t newButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newUserModal">
                Add user
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- New User Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="newUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newUserModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="newUserModalLabel">New user</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" method="post" id="new-user-form" class="needs-validation" action="<?= base_url(); ?>test/newUser" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <label for="inputFirstName">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputFirstName" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Invalid input
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <label for="inputLastName">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputLastName" id="inputLastName" placeholder="" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Invalid input
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="avatar-upload">
                                <div class="avatar-edit">
                                    <input type='file' name="index" id="indexImageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
                                    <label class="text-center" for="indexImageUpload"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="avatar-preview">
                                    <div id="indexImage" style="background-image: url(https://ryanacademy.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/user-placeholder.png)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="avatar-upload">
                                <div class="avatar-edit">
                                    <input type='file' name="picture1" id="picture1Upload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
                                    <label class="text-center" for="picture1Upload"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="avatar-preview">
                                    <div id="picture1" style="background-image: url(https://ryanacademy.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/user-placeholder.png)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="avatar-upload">
                                <div class="avatar-edit">
                                    <input type='file' name="picture2" id="picture2Upload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
                                    <label class="text-center" for="picture2Upload"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="avatar-preview">
                                    <div id="picture2" style="background-image: url(https://ryanacademy.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/user-placeholder.png)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary closeButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="new-user-form">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First change `<form...` to:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new-user-form" class="needs-validation" action="<?= base_url(); ?>test/newUser" novalidate>
```

Then check this: [Multiple image upload with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778683/multiple-image-upload-with-codeigniter)

Comment: It did not help me a lot. Everywhere I find this multiple file upload, but to me, it is not good. Also, it is just file upload. I want to implement it in a form where I also want to take some other input field and then insert it to my database and save the images too. I have to do this because these three images have their roles. There can not be less or more, and the user also has to know which one gonna be in which role, so I can not do it with multiple input fields.

Comment: If you want to upload 3 separate images than you need multiple input fields. You can space them in the frontend and name them differently so you and the user knows which is which. The current problem is that codeigniter only support 1 image upload per form submission that's why you need a separate library that can handle multiple uploads or write your own implementation. The link that i gave you shows that part and you can simply add it to your own code. There's one more option and that's with ajax upload but with php it would be easier.